# Assistance please! Need applet proofreading

Tags: java, swing, awt, japplet

I really cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong- The Option1 code just shows a white empty text field and Option 2 just says it's not initialized... I could really use some guidance. Thanks in advance

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Option1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

private int click = 0;

public Option1() {
JFrame base = new JFrame ("Button Click Counter");
base.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
base.setSize(500,500);
base.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
button.addActionListener(this);
JTextField count = new JTextField(click);
    this.add(button);
    this.add(count);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        click++; }

    }
```

and the other one

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Option2 extends JApplet implements MouseListener {
double x;
double y;
public void init() {
addMouseListener(this);


JFrame base = new JFrame("Mouse Coordinates");
base.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
base.setSize(500,500);
base.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


JTextField answer = new JTextField(x + "," + y);
}
@Override    
public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();

    this.setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

also, if anyone could offer advice on how to a mouseclick to change the background to a random color (as attempted in Option2), that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: why are you using `JFrame` and `JApplet` together? Both are top-level container and there should be just one.

Comment: @user3218114  So do I change JFrame to JPanel and then use this.add to put it in the applet? please help

Comment: yes as suggested in my post as well. follow the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In Option1

`JApplet` by default use `BorderLayout` and you can add just one component in each section north, south, east, west and center. If you add another component in same section then previous component will be replaced by newly added one.

Use overloaded `add()` method to add it in different section.

for example:

```
this.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
this.add(count); // added in CENTER by default
```

It's better to use `JPanel`. Add components in it and finally add `JPanel` in `JApplet`.

Read more about [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

---

#### In Option2

- Never use `null` layout. There is lots of Layout managers that is designed.

  Please have a look at *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

Comment: for Option1, I did this and now the textfield at the bottom doesn't show anything in it... can you advise?

Comment: what should I display? Call `count.setText("hello")` to set the text in tehe `JTextField` or use `new JTextField("Hello")`. Read more in Java Doc what constructor are you using?

Comment: I need it to display the number of mouse clicks on the 'count' button, so that's what the 'click' variable is meant for

Comment: `count.setText(String.valueOf(click))`

Comment: Did this, and it now shows 0 in the textfield but no change when I hit the button...is 'click' a static variable?

Comment: update the text in action listener method. add `count.setText(String.valueOf(click))` just below `count++`

Comment: When I do this, BlueJ tells me that it can't find the variable 'count' which is the JTextField name and is even in a public method...

Comment: make it instance variable.

Comment: It's not the variable I need, it's the TextField that I'm trying to modify